# Error with 'quasar' when trying to setup a dev vue server on Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to set up a hot-reload enabled dev server for vue on Docker, however, there seems to be some issue with the quasar dependency.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.5.0-alpine3.12
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli \
    && npm install -g @quasar/cli \
    && npm install
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

I build and run the image by:

```
docker image build -t test .
docker container run -it -p 8080:8080 -v $pwd:/app test
```

But then, the error shows up:

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'quasar' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'quasar' of undefined
    at module.exports (/app/node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-quasar/index.js:13:29)
    at /app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:78:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Service.init (/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:76:18)
    at Service.run (/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:215:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js:36:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
```

I also tried to use yarn, but the same result occurred.